# Youtube getting number of views and comments in php

Tags: php, api, youtube

I have a youtube video and a webpage to preview the embedded video from my website.

Under the statics I have a view tag where I want to display the **number of view of my video** from youtube **+**  no of **views from my website** and i also want to display replies as guestbook on that webpage where a visitor can see comments on youtube and comments on my site

How can i get no. of views from youtube in php

How can i get comments and the date they have been submitted and the user posted it on php?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the youtube api's page. I think is enough clear to understand.

For example [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php#Using_community_features) show the things about comments:

Comment: but according to this i cant fetch the time

Comment: If the api does not do the things you want the only way is to scrape the webpage. If you google it you can find tons of tutorial about scraping web page within php.